# What is the difference between get through and get over it?

Tags: word-difference

Do I get it right that if I 'get through' things I make some effort or struggle with something? But if I 'get over' things I always win and it always ends up well?

Comment: Does it mean when I am prepared to get through something that I am not absolutely confident of victory but if I am prepared to get over something I am?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea regarding "'get through' things" is basically correct. You are working through some situation with extra effort.

But when you *get over* things, it means to move past something that is needlessly slowing you down. For example:

> I know you really miss your ex-girlfriend. But you really need to **get over it** and fine someone new.